# R: FOR-loop not working even though my (similar) WHILE-loop does work

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I have to make a for-loop that makes a vector which produces the symbols of all the cryptocurrencies that had a market cap change in the past 24 hours of more than 10 percent (absolute). I have made a while-loop that works, however I can't seem to figure out how to make the for-loop working. Does anyone have any clues as to why the for-loop doesn't work?

I have the same problem for the very next exercise. I have a working while-loop, but my for-loop doesn't work. For this one we have to provide market data for 3 given cryptocurrencies.

Below is all the code regarding the problem.

Code of first problem:

For-loop:

```
volatile <- vector()
i <- 1

for (i in nrow(mdata)) {
  if (abs(mdata[i, "market_cap_change_percentage_24h"]) >= 10) {
    volatile <- c(volatile, mdata[i, "symbol"])
  }
}
```

While-loop:

```
volatile <- vector()
i <- 1

while(i <= nrow(mdata)) {
  if(abs(mdata[i, "market_cap_change_percentage_24h"]) >= 10) {
    volatile <- c(volatile, mdata[i, "symbol"])
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Code of second problem:

For-loop:

```
coins <- c("polkadot","bitcoin","ethereum")
overview <- data.frame(id = character(0), average_daily_price = numeric(0), sd = numeric(0))
i <- 1

for (i in length(coins)) {
  mchart <- get_chart(coins[i])
  average_daily_price <- mean(mchart[, 2])
  sd <- sd(mchart[,2])
  overview <- rbind(overview, c(coins[i], average_daily_price, sd))
  i <- i + 1
}
colnames(overview) <- c("id", "average daily price", "sd")
```

(I've tried the for-loop both with and without the "i <- i + 1" part.)

While-loop:

```
coins <- c("polkadot","bitcoin","ethereum")
overview <- data.frame(id = character(0), average_daily_price = numeric(0), sd = numeric(0))
i <- 1

while(i <= length(coins)) {
  mchart <- get_chart(coins[i])
  average_daily_price <- mean(mchart[, 2])
  sd <- sd(mchart[, 2])
  overview <- rbind(overview, c(coins[i], average_daily_price, sd)) 
  i <- i + 1
}
colnames(overview) <- c("id", "average daily price", "sd")
```

(get_chart is a function already provided for in our r-project. If anyone wants to reproduce the code, use the code below at the top of your r-project, if not, this part can be skipped.)

```
options(scipen=999)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

get_market <- function(page) {
  Sys.sleep(2)
  url <- sprintf("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=EUR&page=%s",page)
  data <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(content(GET(url), as="text"), flatten = TRUE))
  return(data)
}

get_chart <- function(coin_id) {
  Sys.sleep(2)
  url <- sprintf("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/%s/market_chart?vs_currency=EUR&days=30&interval=daily",coin_id)
  data <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(content(GET(url), as="text"), flatten = TRUE))
  return(data)
}

mdata <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:5) {
  mdata <- rbind(mdata,get_market(i))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because R is vectorized you often do not need a loop at all.  E.g.,

```
mtcars[mtcars$mpg > 28, 'disp']
[1] 78.7 75.7 71.1 95.1
```

For your first case:

```
volitile <- mdata[abs(mdata$market_cap_change_percentage_24h >=
10), 'symbol']
```

should work.  It extracts the rows that pass the test and returns your column of interest.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It doesn't work entirely, so I hoped you could help me fix it. If I enter it in R it does provide the right number of cryptocurrencies that exceed 10% in daily market cap change in percentage in the past 24h, however, since it only returns "TRUE" or "FALSE" it only returns 1 or 0. So whenever a "1" (bigger than 10%) appears, the first "symbol" from the symbols list appears, which is always Bitcoin (since it is grouped on total market cap). As a result, I have a vector containing "btc" 34 times, while it should contain 34 different symbols. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Nevermind. I noticed that the bracket was on the wrong place, which caused the formula to break. The bracket was first placed after the 10, but when changing it to be after the 24h it worked. Thanks a lot for helping me out!

How it was:
volatile <- mdata[abs(mdata$market_cap_change_percentage_24h >=
10), 'symbol']

How it is now:
volatile <- mdata[abs(mdata$market_cap_change_percentage_24h) >=
10, 'symbol']

Answer (score 0):

Your 'for' loop only has one value, i.e.

```
for (i in nrow(mdata))...
```

should be replaced with

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mdata))...
```

Comment: Yeah that's true ofcourse OMG I feel so stupid that I didn't realize that earlier haha, the smallest things..... Thanks for helping out!